# Embedding PNG images into an email in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, email, embedded-resource

I am having issues getting a PNG to render as an embedded image in an email.  All I am trying to do is embed a company logo in the bottom of an email.

The image is a resource in my project.

Here is code I am using to generate the email body text and alternate views:

```
string body =
    @"<html><body><b>Please do not respond to this message</b><br/><br/>" +
     "<img src='cid:companyLogo' width='100px'/></body></html>";

Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.logo_dark_background);
MemoryStream logoStream = new MemoryStream();
logo.Save(logoStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
LinkedResource companyLogo = new LinkedResource(logoStream);
companyLogo.ContentId = "companyLogo";
companyLogo.ContentType = new ContentType("image/jpg");
AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
    body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
av.LinkedResources.Add(companyLogo);
message.AlternateViews.Add(av);
```

Please note that 'message' is a `MailMessage` object created earlier on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your stream's position is at the end of the stream after saving the logo.

Immediately after the `logo.Save()` call, you can set `logoStream.Position = 0` to reset it to the beginning.

Also don't forget to dispose of your stream, most likely in a `using` statement.